# python urllib is getting error

Tags: windows, python-3.x, urllib

**I WANT TO GET ALL TEXT FROM A WEBPAGE**

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
source=urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com')
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

**THIS IS MY ERROR:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test/web.py", line 5, in 
    soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 165, in **init**
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

**I TRIED SIMILAR CODES BUT THE SAME ERROR WILL OCCUR....WHAT THE REASON?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. urlopen return "http.client.HTTPResponse" object not content. If you want get content you must use the read method. For example:

> source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com').read()

2. You got this help message: **"Do you need to install a parser library (lxml)?"**. Just install this package: `pip install lxml`